# Change value based on what clicked from dropdown menu in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down-menu with a list from my C# model. Now I want to change a value based on what I choose from the menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Bereich").val('@Model.Bereich').change('click', function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this) == "Something") {
        $('#kst').val(123);
      }
      
      if ($(this) == "Somethingelse") {
        $('#kst').val(345);
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

I am quite new to jQuery so I am not sure how to get an element from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main issues in your code. Firstly `change('click', fn)` isn't valid syntax. Given that we're dealing with a `select` element I assume you're trying to create a `change` event handler so the code should be `on('change', fn)` instead.

Secondly, `$(this)` will give you a jQuery object. This will never be equal to a string value so the conditions never hit. I assume you're trying to test the values of the selected items to use `val()` for this.

Note in the following example that I stored `#kst` in a jQuery object and referenced it repeatedly where needed to save accessing the DOM, which is where most performance is lost in JS. Also note that you can access `val()` directly from the `select` element - you don't need to retrieve the `option:selected` element within it.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $kst = $('#kst');

  $("#Bereich").val('@Model.Bereich').on('change', function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
      let value = $(this).val();
      
      if (value === "Something") {
        $kst.val(123);
      } 
      
      if (value === "Somethingelse") {
        $kst.val(345);
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the answer didn't work for me. 

Can the Problem be the id or that  use @Html.DropDownListFor?

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBereich, Model.Bereich, "Bereich auswählen", new { @id = "Bereich", @class = "form-control", @Required = true })`

Comment: That MVC control will still generate a standard HTML `select` element so the above should work. Could you please copy the HTML output from the browser and paste it in to your question so we can create a working example of the issue

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to look at the HTML output. The values weren't strings but numbers. "Something" had the Value 1 so instead of  comparing it to the Value "Something" I should have compared it like this: `value === "1" `
That change fixed it.